# Is it possible to update a page for all users on it using only an express server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

I am building a web app and one of the functions is adding songs to a song queue. Basically there are several different rooms and each of the rooms properties(including the song queue) are stored on the server in a array. I use app.post to send a new song url to the server which then uses that url and adds it to the appropriate room.

Right now, when one person adds a song to the queue only their page is updated. Other people who are in the same room do not receive those updates unless they add their own song and the server returns them the new song queue(the server returns an updated song queue everytime someone adds one).

I believe there is a way to do the real time updates using socket.io but I am pressed for time and am wondering if there is a way to achieve the desired outcome using pure express node.js so I won't need to change everything.

Backend:

```
let rooms = [];

//other stuff that makes these things functional

/***ADD TO QUEUE***/
app.post('/api/addToQueue', async (req,res) => {
    console.log('Add To Queue Request Recieved');
    const activeRoom = req.body.activeRoom;
    const enteredURL = req.body.enteredURL;
    let newQueue;
    for(let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++){
        //locates the room to update
        if(rooms[i].roomCode === activeRoom){
            rooms[i].songQueue.push(enteredURL);
            console.log('Updated Queue');
            newQueue = rooms[i].songQueue;
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(newQueue);
    console.log('Sent New Queue');
    console.log(rooms);
});
```

FrontEnd

```
//inside the add to queue button component which contains the input bar as well
addToQueue = async () => {
        const activeRoom = this.props.getRoom();
        await fetch('/api/addToQueue', {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({activeRoom: activeRoom, enteredURL: this.state.enteredURL})
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(newQueue => this.props.onAddToQueue(newQueue));
        //onAddToQueue changes the state of another component which then renders in the added song as a 
        paragraph element.
    }
```

My file pathing has my frontend inside the backend.

Would love some help :) TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can add setInterval() built-in function that running every few seconds to check a value update or not.
so that when one person adds a song to the queue the other people who are in the same room can receive those updates.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options for real-time web apps

1. sockets: if you need two-way communication
2. server-sent events: only the server can send info to frontend
3. polling: Make a request every certain time to the server

The first two need server changes (the second is easier), the third is just frontend change. All of them have their pros and cons, but I am sure you can find them and make a decision.

Comment: I'll have a look at them all. Thank you.